# Find My Device says "can't reach device", but I can make it ring

Tags: android-device-manager

I'm having a bizarre issue with the Android Device Manager. Basically when I try to look up my Nexus 9 tablet, I cannot see its location, and it looks like this:

[image: Device Manager screenshot]

As you can see, it somehow does display the charge level and the name of the WiFi network it's connected to. More importantly, when I click the play sound button, **it immediately starts ringing**.

So this is clearly not true. How can I fix this and make it so that I can track my tablet's location again?

Comment: Wifi/ data could be off on the tablet preventing location finding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. Apparently this happens when location services are turned on, but fail to produce a location.

In my case, the tablet's location mode was set to GPS only, but the GPS sensors are busted and don't work. Switching to battery saving mode in Settings → Location solved this issue.